# Persist object within entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4

My problem is very simple !

**2 entities :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tournament")
 */
class Tournament
{
    …
    …
    …

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Match", mappedBy="tournament")
     */

    …

    protected $matches;

    public function start()
    {
        $this->addMatch(new Match());
    }
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="match")
 */
class Match
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Tournament", inversedBy="matches")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $tournament;
}
```

I need to persist the new Match I created with the `start()` function. Is it possible ? Or maybe it's a very bad way to do it.

Thanks !!

Siriru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add: `cascade={"persist"}` to options on your `$matches` property in `Tournament` class. Now when you do:

```
$myTournament->start();
$em->persist($myTournament);
$em->flush();
```

Match record will be created in DB automatically by Doctrine.

Comment: Also need to make sure that Tournament::addMatch($match) also calls $match->setTournament($this).

Comment: Yes, It works but during the persist : `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO match (step, time1, time2, player1_id, player2_id, winner_id, type_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [0, null, null, 1, 2, null, 53]:` obviously I set nullable=true in the correct fieds. `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: This usually happens when you didnt run doctrine:schema:update after changing entities

Comment: I tested again and again my no result. Any idea ?